# lyx.~ files and general organisation

Tags: lyx, revision-control

I'm wondering what exactly the lyx.~ files are and what people do with them.

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108075/what-are-the-lyx-files-for) that they are backups of the file in case the save fails. If that's the case, what is best practice to do with them? A comment suggests they can be saved to a different directory?

More generally, what is the best practice in saving your lyx files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the accepted answer from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13108146/311834):

> They are files created by your editor. Traditionally files that end
>   with a tilde are to be seen as backups of files with the same name but
>   without the tilde.

You don't need to care about them. The LyX editor will delete them in the same way they were created. That is, transparent to the user.
They are meant for the program (for example, in case of a sudden crash of the application), not for the user.

I encourage you to save your lyx files so that they are versioned, in a way understandable *to you*, rather than to the program you are using.
For example, with versioning tools like [git](https://www.lyx.org/HowToUseGIT) or with other backup programs that automatically save subsequent version of the same file once its modifications are saved on drive (dropbox is an example, but there are many others).